# JavaFx Runnable jar doesn't work if class extends ImageView

Tags: image, javafx, executable-jar

I have made a snake game in JavaFx and it's working proper, but when I export it into executable jar file(I'm working on Intellij) it doesn't show me these Scenes that are including the classes extending ImageView .

Menu Scene that I can open because it doesn't
contains the classes extending ImageView:

[image]

but I can't open the main Scene ,because it contains such class :

```
package Controllers;

import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class Head extends ImageView
{
    public Head()
    {
        setImage(new Image("/img/headRIGHT.png"));
        setLayoutX(420);
        setLayoutY(300);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to add the folder with images to jar Path ?

Comment: in the folder with your jar, put a folder named img. Inside that folder put the image `headRight.png`.

Comment: It's possible to add resource files to the jar archive itself. [Take a look at the contents of the jar file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html) and check, if `img/headRIGHT.png` is listed (or if there is a path ending with `headRIGHT.png` at all).

Comment: unrelated to your problem: don't extend controls (nor any other class) if you can achieve the same by configuration